# I removed windows partition from dualboot ubuntu, but now I can't repair windows even after trying to install through dvd-iso?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

my machine is dualboot windows and UBUNTU 17 (EFI). before a year I installed Ubuntu as dualboot with windows 10. both OS were working perfectly.
**I started loving Ubuntu and thought there would be no need of windows in future, so I deleted windows partition from Ubuntu.** 
But now I wanted to UNDO this and to reinstall windows with dualboot environment.
Although I deleted Windows partition, In splash screen there is option of windows but now I can't boot into windows. How can I copy necessary files from windows-iso file from DVD to its partition from ubuntu?

*How can I UNDO this and how to make both OS working as it was before?*

Comment: also, I can't install windows from scratch and then Ubuntu. As I have more than 100gb of data in Ubuntu. but thanks for reply.

Comment: "But now I wanted to UNDO this and to reinstall windows with dualboot environment." do you plan to remove ubuntu? If not, why not install virtualbox and windows inside it.

Comment: @Rinzwind, VirtualBox slows when I use it for development purpose. as my machine's configurations are - core i3, 4gb ram, 2.00ghz processor. In Ubuntu I have some problems with Mongodb and sometimes others problem are tough to solve as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813305/mongo-shell-working-in-ubuntu-but-mongod-start-doesnt-work/48814209#48814209), so that I wanted to go back to windows but keeping Ubuntu as dualboot.

Comment: If you deleted Windows partition it is gone. UEFI keeps entry and ESP - efi system partition probably still has a /EFI/Windows folder as you did not delete them. If Windows was UEFI, you must reinstall in UEFI boot mode & need Windows partitions. BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations Be sure to have good backups.